# Find Zone ID of list view webpart remotely

Tags: web-services, client-object-model, xslt-list-view-web-part, web-part-zone

How to find the `ZoneID` of a list view webpart remotely?

- We can use any means to get the information; CSOM, JSON, web services or hacks. But we cannot use server-side code.
- We can know any information of the web part beforehand except the `ZoneID`

For example: We know the Id of a list view webpart, and we know the page where it is. Now we need to know its `ZoneID`...

Challenges:

- CSOM doesn't allow us to get `ZoneID` from `WebPartDefinition`
- Web services do, but list view webparts do not allow export of properties (`Id` or `ZoneID`), so we cannot use `WebPartPages.asmx` and `GetWebPartProperties2` for list view web parts (?)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I have been struggling with the same problem and I thought I should add the solution I have come up with for future searches.

Zone ID doesn't seem to be exposed for most web parts, specifically the ones using `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"` (where all properties are returned as "property" elements).

If your web part happens to be using `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"` (where properties are returned as elements on their own) then `Zone ID` will be one of the XML elements returned as part of the web part definition when you use the SharePoint web service `GetWebPart2` or `GetWebPartProperties2`.

For the web parts where you don't get the `Zone ID` your only option left is getting the page contents using `GetWebPartPage` web service and parsing it.

Within the page you'll have the web part elements within `"WebPartPages:WebPartZone"` elements (each representing a different zone).

These web part elements have the `ID` of the web part as well as the `ZoneID` within their main XML node. So you can use regex to fish it out.

Here is a very simple regex (make sure you set the case-insensitive option on whatever environment you're running this on):

```
ZoneID="(.\*?)".\*?0a32c6f6-ee05-4c8e-ba7a-587c0c67c382
```